# Online .Net Coding

Tags: asp.net, .net

This may not be a platform for such a question but still I'm curious to know whether i can practice visual studio coding online. Does anyone know such a website?

What i meant by practice is to write and run .net programs online. Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best I have seen is http://www.coderun.com/ide/ . Awesome.

Its not like some other websites which only allows you to run some snippet of code. Code run is like mini IDE where you can not only create project but also debug them and share the code. And that's all FREE

Comment: Is it possible to load a project from our local drive?

Comment: Yes, It has a upload option. Just try hand on on this.

Comment: @Maheep: +1 for sharing a nice url

Answer (score 1):

you can use Microsoft virtual lab
use this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa570323)

Comment: My network is too slow to handle it. Thanks by the way. Its helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/) is another website that you can run your code.

Other compilers include [codepad](http://codepad.org/) and [compilr](http://compilr.com/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Actually i was looking for a web-programming ide. This too will come in handy. Thank You